# Airplanes and the earth’s rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

A helicopter is on a moving treadmill, suddenly becomes airborne and hovers over the moving treadmill. The pilot of the helicopter must consider the movement of the treadmill if they wish to briefly land the helicopter on the exact spot that the helicopter took off from.

My question: How is a hypothetical airplane taking off from a due east-west runway different from my hypothetical helicopter taking off from a moving treadmill?

Comment: "and suddenly becomes airborne" You mean... it takes off using its rotor? Your helicopter setup is not clear to me. Does it keep the same forwards speed as the treadmill below it once it's in the air? What do you mean by "briefly land"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the air is in motion as well, when considering the rotation of the earth. It isn't on the treadmill. The airplane taking off is "carried forwards" by the already moving air. The helicopter taking off will have a forwards motion which is suddenly resisted by the stationary air.

Winds, air fluctuations etc. might of course alter this locally.

Comment: Air is factored in to the planning of an airplane flight.....the 1,000 mph west-east rotation of the earth is not.

Comment: I do believe that I have found the answer-it has nothing to do with air.

Comment: If you have found an answer yourself, it is always appreciated if you also post it here as an answer to your question.

Comment: Things that are connected to the earth are just like a passenger on a plane....the passenger is not affected by the speed of the plane or the rotation of the earth......the passenger is essentially part of the plane......the plane; though aloft; is still part of the earth by way of gravity......Gravity is a tether that connects the plane to the earth,and renders it immune to the force of rotation......this would explain why a butterfly can travel Due West without contending with a 1,000 mph resistance; or trace Due East without contending with a 1,000 mph force behind it......

Comment: Flight is accomplished by pushing against air; but; by no means is it a break with gravity....the airplane and the butterfly are still one with the earth,even though the gravitational tether cannot be seen.

Comment: Even though I see an airplane as an airborne vehicle,I now believe it is truly an earthbound vehicle.....it is strongly connected to the earth by way of gravity; in spite of the fact that it can fly......

Comment: Creatures of flight are no different from a rock on the ground in terms of being connected to the earth by gravity and unaffected by it’s rotation.

Comment: Even at 32,000 ft,when an airplane’s engine shuts down; its gravitational tether pays it a call.....it returns to earth because it truly never LEFT the earth...

Comment: @DanielDavidHiggins, Gravity only attracts the airplane toward the center of the Earth (i.e., straight down.) It does not drag the airplane toward the East. Momentum is why the Earth's surface does not immediately leave the airplane behind at the moment when the airplane lifts off. The airplane was moving eastward along with the Earth's surface just before it lifted off, and its momentum keeps it moving eastward. Longer term, it keeps moving along with the Earth because the Earth's atmosphere rotates along with the Earth (ignoring weather), and the airplane flies _in_ the atmosphere.

Answer (score 3):

> how is a hypothetical airplane taking off from a Due East-West Runway different from my hypothetical helicopter taking off from a moving treadmill?

Typically the air does not flow at the same speed as a treadmill. You can make the treadmill and earth examples analogous by matching the relative airspeed, otherwise that is the key difference.

For aircraft the important thing is the airspeed. The airspeed (neglecting wind) over the earth is the same as the earth's rotation. The airspeed over a treadmill is not the same as the treadmill's speed. This is the key difference which cannot be neglected.

Comment: In real life most runways do have air flowing over them. It's called "wind". If you want to land a helicopter the same point as you took off, you need to take the wind into account.

Comment: @alephzero that is not what I wrote. I wrote that the air does not flow at the same speed as the treadmill, not that there is no airflow. In the analogy between a treadmill and an East-West runway (at the equator) there is not a 1000 mph wind at the equator as there would be for the analogous treadmill.

Comment: My hypothetical question is without wind-it is meant to address the rotation of the earth; and why this rotation is not factored in to the navigation of airplanes.

Comment: In the original explanation; the airplane is regarded exactly like a passenger INSIDE the plane; and; I have trouble with this concept; as the hypothetical plane has become airborne; it is not earthbound;it is flying above a planet that is rotating......the plane is not a passenger; it is a vehicle,and I do not understand how a vehicle is subject to the physics that apply to a passenger.

Comment: @DanielDavidHiggins, re, "My...question is without wind..." Do you mean to say that the wind speed is zero? If so, is it zero as measured by somebody who is moving with the "treadmill?" or is it zero as measured by somebody who is standing on the ground? They can't both measure zero. "Wind" is air. An aircraft, when it is flying is _embedded_ in the air. It maneuvers _through_ the air by pushing against the air, and the pushing changes the way in which the air moves. It makes no sense to ignore the air in any question about an aircraft.

Comment: As I mentioned; my hypothetical question is focused on The Earth’s Rotation; and why it is not factored in to the navigation of airplanes.

Comment: As a planes pushes through the air that it is embedded in,etc.,etc.,etc......the earth beneath it is rotating.....this rotation is not factored in to the navigation of the plane.....wind....high wind.....no wind....It is not factored in.

Comment: @DanielDavidHiggins, The air, in which the airplane is embedded, tends to be carried along with the rotating Earth. If aircraft navigators don't account for the rotation of the Earth, it's because they are navigating relative to the Earth through air that, on average, moves along with the Earth. You didn't say what "without wind" means, but if it means, that a person standing on the ground would measure a wind speed of zero, then that's exactly what I'm talking about. "Wind speed==0" means that the air mass, on average, is moving at exactly the same speed as the Earth.

Comment: @DanielDavidHiggins I have updated my answer with another paragraph addressing your comments here.

Comment: A plane flying Due East,at the equator,at 200 mph,over the Earth,which rotates West to East at 1,000mph......and this rotation is not factored into the plane’s  journey....

Comment: @DanielDavidHiggins, maybe you should ask about ballistics instead of asking about aircraft. (E.g., What is the path over the ground of an artillery shell that is fired due North from the equator?) An artillery shell doesn't maneuver through air by pushing on air. To the extent that a shell interacts with air, those interactions are an annoying complication that gunners would rather be rid of. Artillery shells would work just fine in vacuum, but long-range gunners still _would_ have to account for the Coriolis effect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_artillery#Fire_control

Comment: @DanielDavidHiggins As a simpler thought exercise, think about why, when you stand on the ground and jump, the earth doesn't fly past your feet at 1600 km/h while you're in the air.

Comment: I feel that I have a grasp of the Passenger -on-the-Plane concept.....and I must say that I see the passenger and plane as two entirely different entities,and,with regard to flight; one is clearly a vehicle,the other is INSIDE ( or part of) the vehicle......inside the vehicle; the passenger does not have to propel himself at 200mph in order to travel-but the vehicle does....the psychics affecting the vehicle are different from the physics affecting the passenger.

Comment: @DanielDavidHiggins why are you ignoring the air? The air does not move with a treadmill. The air does move with the earth. Why would you expect them to be the same when they are not? Do you not recognize the importance of the **air** for an **air**plane?

Comment: This is not about me.

Comment: @DanielDavidHiggins it is your question so it is at least partly about you. In this case your question seems to be based on focusing on the ground to the exclusion of the air. Why are you ignoring the air?

Comment: I asked a HYPOTHETICAL question.....the question itself is being questioned.....my MOTIVE  is being questioned...but the QUESTION is ignored.

Comment: @DanielDavidHiggins I answered your question in the answer itself. The question has not been ignored whatsoever. Since you appear to not accept the answer where I explained that the air cannot be ignored, I am indeed asking your motivation for ignoring the air. If I understood that motive I might be able to get at the root of the question. The question you asked has been answered, but you are not satisfied, which usually means that the question you asked is not what was bothering you.

Comment: I am not the subject-not even in the slightest degree.

Comment: Then this answer is a correct answer to the question you asked, and your dissatisfaction with the answer is not relevant not even in the slightest degree.

Comment: The declaration that the answer is correct;the declaration of my possible dissatisfaction;and the declaration of my possible dissatifaction’s irrelevance are not the subject either

Comment: Indeed. The question is answered and all of your subsequent comments and the responses are pointless.

Comment: When a discussion focuses on WHO is right; instead of WHAT is right; the discussion strays from the subject; it veers off course,and and yields nothing.

Comment: For my part, it was never about who was right. It was about trying to understand the question that you didn’t actually ask but wanted to ask. You seem to have taken it as a personal attack when it was personal but in no way an attack.

Comment: I simply stated that I am not the subject......I have no comment on the other conclusions drawn.

Comment: It’s too bad. If you were willing to open up a bit and be the subject then perhaps you could have expressed your underlying question.

Comment: My interpretation of this exchange is vastly different than the one presented here.

Comment: I agree with that.

Answer (score 3):

There are already answers to what was actually asked, but from the OP's comments I gather this is not what they meant. So I'll try to guess what they meant to ask, which is

> Suppose we had a way to propulsively move around an earth with no atmosphere. If we wanted to go east to west, could we just lift off the ground and wait for the earth to rotate away beneath us?

The answer to that question is no. Because at the moment of liftoff, you are carrying the exact west-to-east momentum you need to stay where you are relative to the ground, even if you lift off the ground (if you go up really high that is not true anymore, then you need to work with angular momentum). To go west, you need to change your momentum relative to the surface of the earth, i.e. accelerate. So even with no air present (which is the main real-world factor in this), you don't have to account for the rotation of the earth, because you are already going at the same speed the surface is moving before takeoff, and your body/aircraft has inertia to keep that momentum.

For north-south movement in a straight line you actually need to compensate for this momentum you already have (because the surface speed is different at different latitudes), which appears as the Coriolis force.